# URL outputs JSON - PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a problem and I can't find the error. It can't be a syntax error.

Basically, the following outputs nothing even though the URL outputs JSON.

```
$jsonurl = 'http://www.geopostcode.org.uk/api/SE92EQ.json';
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
$json_output = json_decode($json);

foreach ( $json_output->wgs84 as $results )
{
echo "{$results->lat}<br />";
echo "{$results->lon}<br />";
```

Help me find the error. wgs84 is the parent and yet, lat and lon can't be found.

Thank you.

Edit: Print of $json_output is found here - http://pastebin.com/ZQRxhjRJ

Comment: What happened to doing your own debugging? ...

Comment: Post `print_r($json_output);` in the OP.

Comment: Print of json output -> http://pastebin.com/ZQRxhjRJ

Answer (score 1):

When you `print_r($json_output);` (as suggested by h2ooooooo), you'll see the following part

```
[wgs84] => stdClass Object
    (
        [lat] => 51.446973
        [lon] => 0.078981
    )
```

This means that `wgs84` is an object and not an array. So why would you iterate over it?

```
echo $json_output->wgs84->lat."<br />";
echo $json_output->wgs84->lon."<br />";
```

et voila.

Comment: That said, even if it *was* an array you **still** wouldn't iterate through it.

Comment: True. True. Silly mistake on my behalf. Thank you.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Can you elaborate? I'm not familiar with their api, but couldn't it be an array of objects that somehow belong together and all have lat/long?

Comment: @kingkero If it wasn't an object but an array (and not an array with an array) you'd just access it as `$json_output->wgs84['lat']`.

Comment: @CodyRaspien If this answer is the solution to your question, please consider marking it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a second argument `true` to the `json_decode()` function. This will return an array instead of an object.

Your code should look like this:

```
$jsonurl = 'http://www.geopostcode.org.uk/api/SE92EQ.json';
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
$json_output = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ( $json_output['wgs84'] as $results ) {
    echo "{$results['lat']}<br />";
    echo "{$results['lon']}<br />";
}
```

Comment: `$results` wouldn't have a `'lat'` or `'lon'` key but rather be the value of `lat` and `lon` (for two iterations).